# iTextSharp extraction cyrillic characters

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-reader, pdf-extraction

In my project I need to read a PDF document. This pdf contains ukrainian & russian characters. the PDFReader read all characters in this pdf but the cirillic characters missing in output. I'm try to use encoding but it not helped. What can I do with this chars?

```
   public static string GetText(string filePath)
    {
        ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        if (File.Exists(filePath)){
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
            for (int i = 1; i < pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                string thePage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, i, strategy);
                text.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
                thePage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(thePage)));
                text.Append(thePage);
            }                pdfReader.Close();
        }            return text.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please share the PDF in question for analysis. IText usually does extract Cyrillic characters as long as the used fonts contain the required information for text extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTextSharp is an outdated product that is no longer supported, probably there are problems with text extraction. Here is a simple example of how the extraction text works in ITEXT 7 (the code is in java, but everything is the same for c#).

```
    String filePath = "test.pdf";
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(i);
        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        String thePage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(page, strategy);
        text.append(thePage);
    }
    pdfReader.close();
    System.out.print(text);
```

The code is about the same as in your example, but the text extracts